# If $f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is entire, and $u^2(x,y) = v^2 (x,y)$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I see that if I considered:
$f^2 (x+iy) = u^2 - v^2 + 2iuv = 2iuv$, then $f^2$ is constant and so the square root of a constant will be constant, hence $f$ is constant.

However, I want to prove it with the following, and I somehow showed that it's the zero function?

Since $f$ is entire, then $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$.

Also, using $u^2 = v^2$, differentiating w.r.t to $x$ and $y$ gives
$u\cdot u_x = v \cdot v_x$
and $u\cdot u_y = v \cdot v_y$.

Multiplying the two equations together, we have
$u^2 \cdot u_x \cdot u_y = v^2 \cdot v_x \cdot v_y$.
Using the CRE, we have that $u^2\frac{u_x}{v_y}= v^2 \frac{v_x}{u_y} \implies u^2 = -v^2$.
But $u^2 = v^2$. Hence, $u \equiv 0 \equiv v$ and so $f$ is the constant zero function?

Comment: Does $u^2(x,y)$ mean $(u(x,y))^2$?

Comment: Consider the real part of $f^2$. Then $\exp(if^2)$ is constant, etc.

Comment: Yes it does, sorry

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I thought that if $f^2 = 0 + 2iuv$, I could immediately conclude that $f$ is constant since $f^2$ will be constant (using CRE)? Why do I have to take the exponential?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic case of proving something incorrect by secretly dividing both sides of the equation by $0$. Here $u_y$ and $v_y$ are both $0$ so dividing by them isn't allowed.

With a little care you can modify this to a valid proof by contradiction.

Comment: Ah I see. What if I were to "flip" the sides and then multiply them together similarly? e.g.:  $uv u_x v_y = uv u_y v_x$ so $u_x ^2 = -u_y ^2$ which means $u_x ^2 + u_y ^2$. But sum of two real squares equal to zero means each component equals to zero, so $u_x = 0 = u_y$.  
Is this only valid for $uv \neq 0$?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours That seems reasonable although you are using $uv \ne 0$. There is a silly case distinction to make here.

Comment: Thank you. A slightly related question - do you know more examples of this type of question where they give some relationship between $\Im (f)$ and $\Re(f)$ which implies that $f$ would be constant?

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours I don't know a list offhand but several questions like that are showing up in the "related" section to the right